# Does CP determine the aggressiveness of a wild Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have started to notice a potential pattern with wild Pokemon. It would appear that the higher their CP, the more aggressive they are; that is, they jump more, dodge more, or "attack" more. Is this true, or am I just imagining things? Are there specific levels of CP where certain behaviors are more prevalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a concrete answer to this, but if you're interested in some approximations here is a good [**Google Spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jj4_DGoaI-KZsm7vqNv1RVi3tZWrjiFoSPagwO9qfQM/pubhtml) listing the Catch Rates and Flee Rates of Pokemon. See below for explanation of the columns.

- **Base Catch Rate** and **Flee Rate** are for Pokemon with a decent CP (not too high, not too low)
- **Effective Catch Rate** takes into consideration both Base Catch Rate and Flee Rate to determine what are the chances of you catching the Pokemon without it escaping
- **-50% Catch Rate** is for Pokemon with much higher CP
- **+50% Catch Rate** for lower CP Pokemon
- **+100% Catch Rate** for very low CP Pokemon

Credits to the Google Spreadsheet goes to this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4usq2d/analysis_of_pokemon_catch_rates/). The OP of that post did quite a lot of math to figure this stuff out so kudos to him!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be pretty true. From my experience, the higher cp, and evolution stage, the more aggressive the pokemon behaves. This can be indicated by the color of the shrinking circle. while a circle is green, the pokemon is generally pretty docile. However, if you find a 2nd or 3rd evolution stage with 600 or so cp, the shrinking circle will be orange, and presumably, will continue to red as it gets higher.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question since it doesn't address how the Pokemon behaves, just the catch difficulty as indicated by the circle

Comment: i dont believe niantic has released any sort of information about that. the only thing we have to go off of is our personally experience. from my experience, they indeed get more aggressive as their cp, or evolution stage increases. as for specific "brackets" of behavior in relation to cp, we have no way to consistently measure this without a large amount of weak and strong pokemon to contrast.