# Determining Catchability of a Pokemon without wasting a Pokeball

Tags: pokemon-go

My question is sort of related to [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/277646/63009), but I am more concerned about saving pokeballs.

When you encounter a pokemon, generally you can assume that the higher CP, the more difficulty you'd have in catching it. However it seems to me that you cannot tell for sure until you use a pokeball and see the green/yellow/red circle.

The problem is that you might waste a pokeball. For example, for pidgey farming, I'd prefer to only get easy to catch pidgeys. Why waste great balls or razz berries on a low CP orange catch rate pidgey right?

While trying to stay true to the spirit of free-to-play, pokeballs are a limited resource. So is there anyway to determine the catchability before using a pokeball? Or maybe there's a way to cancel a pokeball throw (while you are still holding down the pokeball)?

Note: I am not concerned about the specific pokemon catch rate, just if it is an orange~red pidgey, I don't wanna attempt to catch it.

Comment: Yea, if the Pidgey is over 100 cp, it isn't really worth the effort to catch.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can cancel a Pokémon ball throw if you hold the ball still. You simply need to release it, and it will cancel the throw. Though from experience, if you move it slightly while releasing it, it will just drop at your feet. I do this quite often to avoid wasting time trying to catch my 397th of a Pokémon that will require the use of a great ball, or several tries with a Pokéball.

Comment: So basically don't move the your finger at all after holding the ball, and then just release? :)

Comment: @gitsitgo Just don't move it for about a second or so before releasing it.

Comment: You can avoid dropping it at your feet if, instead of holding it still, you flick it downwards.

Answer (score -1):

Answer courtesy of Syncs answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/277655/8350):

> There really isn't a concrete answer to this, but if you're interested
>   in some approximations [here is a good Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jj4_DGoaI-KZsm7vqNv1RVi3tZWrjiFoSPagwO9qfQM/pubhtml) listing
>   the Catch Rates and Flee Rates of Pokemon. See below for explanation
>   of the columns.
>
> - **Base Catch Rate** and **Flee Rate** are for Pokemon with a decent CP (not    too high, not too low)
> - **Effective Catch Rate** takes into consideration both Base Catch Rate    and Flee Rate to determine what are the chances of you
>     catching    the Pokemon without it escaping
> - **-50% Catch Rate** is for Pokemon with much higher CP
> - **+50% Catch Rate** for lower CP Pokemon
> - **+100%    Catch Rate** for very low CP Pokemon
>
> Credits to the [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jj4_DGoaI-KZsm7vqNv1RVi3tZWrjiFoSPagwO9qfQM/pubhtml) goes to this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4usq2d/analysis_of_pokemon_catch_rates/).
>   The OP of that post did quite a lot of math to figure this stuff out
>   so kudos to him!

by this information he provided you can pretend to how to waste a pokeball or not...

for the pokeball to stop you have to just hold your finger still and it will put back but do not swipe a little or you might loss the ball..and if you don't want to catch that pokemon there is a button left upper corner to run from that pokemon...

hope this might help!!

Comment: No links in answer? No idea what the sheet or the google post you are trying to link to are...

Comment: well i'm new here so i added the like in the wrong way..here's the link [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4usq2d/analysis_of_pokemon_catch_rates/) and here is somthing that might help you as well [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4upwaf/what_are_the_factors_that_determine_if_the/)..

Comment: [Google Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jj4_DGoaI-KZsm7vqNv1RVi3tZWrjiFoSPagwO9qfQM/pubhtml)

Comment: Ths answer is quite literally copied from the linked answer - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/277655/72052

Comment: In the future, Mr. K, please include a link a to the answer your quoting and format it as a quoteblock. To do so you just highlight the text you want to quote, and click the quote button (it's right next to the hyperlink button). Thanks!

Comment: thanks man for your kind help.i am new but i will learn in time @Wipqozn. great thanks man!!