# Can a 'chance to catch' percentage be calculated with the color of the circle?

Tags: pokemon-go

It is known that the color of the circle represents if the pokemon is currently hard or easy to catch.

But can that color be converted to a cold, hard number?

Like if it's all the way green, is it always, let's say, a 90% catch rate. And when it's all the way red, 1%?

PS because of the tought that this is a duplicate of [Does CP determine the aggressiveness of a wild Pokemon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277646/does-cp-determine-the-aggressiveness-of-a-wild-pokemon)

1. Not talking about the aggressiveness of the Pokemon. I'm talking about catch rate. If I would be to throw and touch with 100 PokeBalls to that pokemon, how many would break open and how many would catch.
2. This Question has also no relation to CP. I already noticed that the CP has no effect on the color of the circle. I've seen some very low CP (20-40 CP) pokemon with a red circle before. For those wondering, I would say evolved forms have usually harder catchrates compared for the same CP.
3. The question is basically is there a constant between the color of the cicle and the catch rate of the pokemon. Like I said before, would a green circle pokemon always stay in 90 pokeballs out of 100, and would a red circle pokemon stay in only 5 pokeballs out of 100. Looking for probabilities here.

Comment: we can only guess...

Comment: its more like a range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does CP determine the aggressiveness of a wild Pokemon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277646/does-cp-determine-the-aggressiveness-of-a-wild-pokemon)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a dupe. That question is about CP, not the color of the circle.

Comment: I have never noticed the circle changing colour after feeding the pokemon a razz berry. That makes me think that the colour does not directly correlate to a number.

Comment: You've got a point.... But then, the circle color correlates to what?

Comment: And the color does change when you change pokeballs, which means that it is really on the chance that this pokeball has to get that pokemon

Comment: To me, the circle's color seems to take on shades such as light green.  That suggests an actual percentage along the spectrum from green to red.  Good luck to anyone who will reverse engineer that formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a correlation between the circle color and the catch rate of the Pokemon. No specific numbers are known, but a user *has* calculated **approximate** percentages for color thresholds in [this post on the Silph Road reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vs70r/analysis_on_catch_rates_and_encounters/):

> The colors seem to work like this: if the capture rate (remember the formula from the beginning) is less than ≈ 65% the color is yellow. I wasn’t able to test the exact boundaries but my tests showed that around 65 was when the circle turned yellow. Likewise, at ≈ 35% the circle would turn orange. I only encountered a red circle once and the % was 21% so I wasn’t able to even get an approximate value there and I’m not going to assume anything for that with only 1 value in my data set.

---

This is more of an aside, but based on the information in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/57c3im/medal_capture_rate_bonus_what_we_know_what_we_dont/?), the circle color is directly related to level, in addition to species.

Comment: Since the color of the circle doesn't change with the use of a razzberry, I suspect that the color of the circle is simply the *base* catch rate. Then again, with catch bonuses for types now a thing, I have no idea if that bonus is included in the circle color or not.

Comment: @Ellesedil It was confirmed that the medal catch bonus does *not* change the color of the circle. See the second link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

PokeAssistant's [Catch Chance Calculator](https://pokeassistant.com/catchchance) webpage does calculate percentages based on all the catch factors including a colored circle to help you compare.

Answer (score -2):

It can be calculated if not using Razz Berries, Curveballs or hitting Nice/Great/Excellent and hit the Pokémon when the circle becomes the largest, but also depends on your level and the Pokémon level.

The real capture chance of a Pokémon which is allowed to catch is always bigger than 4%, and increases as the Base Capture Rate increases.

This [Pokemon Go catch bonus calculator](http://pokemongohub.net/pokemon-go-catch-bonus-calculator/) may help you.

Answer (score -4):

Answer courtesy of Syncs answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/277655/8350):

> There really isn't a concrete answer to this, but if you're interested
>   in some approximations [here is a good Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jj4_DGoaI-KZsm7vqNv1RVi3tZWrjiFoSPagwO9qfQM/pubhtml) listing
>   the Catch Rates and Flee Rates of Pokemon. See below for explanation
>   of the columns.
>
> - **Base Catch Rate** and **Flee Rate** are for Pokemon with a decent CP (not    too high, not too low)
> - **Effective Catch Rate** takes into consideration both Base Catch Rate    and Flee Rate to determine what are the chances of you
>     catching    the Pokemon without it escaping
> - **-50% Catch Rate** is for Pokemon with much higher CP
> - **+50% Catch Rate** for lower CP Pokemon
> - **+100%    Catch Rate** for very low CP Pokemon
>
> Credits to the [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jj4_DGoaI-KZsm7vqNv1RVi3tZWrjiFoSPagwO9qfQM/pubhtml) goes to this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4usq2d/analysis_of_pokemon_catch_rates/).
>   The OP of that post did quite a lot of math to figure this stuff out
>   so kudos to him!

by this information he provided you can pretend to how to waste a pokeball or not...

for the pokeball to stop you have to just hold your finger still and it will put back but do not swipe a little or you might loss the ball..and if you don't want to catch that pokemon there is a button left upper corner to run from that pokemon...

hope this might help!!

Comment: You should be flagging questions as duplicates rather than posting duplicate answers.